# Getting some strings with using Regex

Tags: c#

Could someone help me how I can get the strings after the English > srt
I only wanna grab this strings:

> /20200623/c1/51/1777469aba625657d69b3cbaefed1387.srt?qd_uid=0&qd_tm=1594275239930&qd_tvid=16385349500&qyid=f0f6a8fe625d5f29422131ad7c466dbf&lid=3

```
"_name": "Vietnamese",
      "_sort": 6,
      "mver": "101",
      "lid": 23,
      "xml": "/20200623/c0/72/e00ed17c479f2700194837e1d3901e32.xml?qd_uid=0&qd_tm=1594275239930&qd_tvid=16385349500&qyid=f0f6a8fe625d5f29422131ad7c466dbf&lid=23",
      "srt": "/20200623/c0/72/41619b14d41606def042d6d267b72de2.srt?qd_uid=0&qd_tm=1594275239930&qd_tvid=16385349500&qyid=f0f6a8fe625d5f29422131ad7c466dbf&lid=23",
      "_selected": false,
      "pre": 0,
      "ie": 0,
      "uuid": "b908453e2869285ef8a1f75599ae85d9",
      "_limited": 1,
      "ssv": 1,
      "webvtt": "/20200623/c0/72/cbc73fb5b7da5282d0697f265e08c87c.vtt?qd_uid=0&qd_tm=1594275239930&qd_tvid=16385349500&qyid=f0f6a8fe625d5f29422131ad7c466dbf&lid=23",
      "ss": 0
    },
    {
      "_name": "English",
      "_sort": 1,
      "mver": "101",
      "lid": 3,
      "xml": "/20200623/c1/51/445603c545708bf234430da417a9469f.xml?qd_uid=0&qd_tm=1594275239930&qd_tvid=16385349500&qyid=f0f6a8fe625d5f29422131ad7c466dbf&lid=3",
      "srt": "/20200623/c1/51/1777469aba625657d69b3cbaefed1387.srt?qd_uid=0&qd_tm=1594275239930&qd_tvid=16385349500&qyid=f0f6a8fe625d5f29422131ad7c466dbf&lid=3",
      "_selected": true,
      "pre": 0,
      "ie": 0,
      "uuid": "c802506ad202e27680b8096ccc18f36d",
      "_limited": 1,
      "ssv": 1,
      "webvtt": "/20200623/c1/51/da547e3c9d716037190173eabfbf4eaf.vtt?qd_uid=0&qd_tm=1594275239930&qd_tvid=16385349500&qyid=f0f6a8fe625d5f29422131ad7c466dbf&lid=3",
      "ss": 0
```

Comment: If this is *JSON*, don't be *regexing* it. *Deserialize* it

Comment: Yes this is json file
can you give me an idea how I can get it without using regex?
I actually Deserialize it with jsonconvert

Comment: The difference is the language
I just wanna grab the English version there too many languages from this source

Comment: Here's the full source for it
https://pastebin.com/raw/rXsiQw4L

Comment: Yes @TheGeneral I already Deserialize it and that's the result
How I can get only that part? I'm new with using json

Comment: Deserialize the JSON, find the array element where _name == "English".

Comment: So what you have is an array, when you deserialize you can just FirstOrDefault for english

Comment: Could you give me an example code @John?

Comment: is this what you mean guys?
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm

Comment: That's certainly one approach, yes.

Comment: Alright this is very interesting. I'm currently exploring parsing with json
thank you guys for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out to get the English link only

```
string json = richTextBox1.Text;
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var subtitle = jObject["data"]["program"]["stl"][8]["srt"]; //[8] is the English
output.Text = subtitle.ToString();
```